# Mi archivo JavaScript solo ejecuta la primera línea de la función

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente error:

Cuando ejecuto el archivo de *JavaScript* al que está conectado con 3 páginas distintas. Agregue un `addEventListener` para que al presionar un logo pueda enviarme a otra página exterior, luego agregué otro `addEventListener` para que un `<div>` haga un seguimiento de un *input range*, pero el problema está en que solo ejecuta el primer `addEventListener`, mientras que el segundo nunca lo llega a realizar.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Este es el código de *JavaScript*:

```js
function lecturas(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0].addEventListener("click",regreso,true);
    document.getElementsByClassName('nf')[0].addEventListener("input", function(){
        alert('#####');
        document.getElementsByClassName("senal")[0].style.marginLeft=(document.getElementsByClassName('val')[0].value*4)+"px";
    },false);
}
        
function regreso(){
    window.location.href="../Principal.html";
}
        
//formR = document.forms["Registro_general"];
//formR.addEventListener("submit",verificacion,false);

window.onload=lecturas;
```

Comment: Busca si hay errores en la consola del navegador. Normalmente se accede con `F12`.

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que document.getElementsByClassName('nf') esté retornando los elementos correctos?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar código HTML relacionado, es la única forma en que podemos ver lo que está pasado y probar para buscar el error.